# Export csv laravel

Tags: php, laravel, export

Не могу открыть файл в блокноте, точнее когда открываю вот такая картина
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываю в excel там все норм:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мой контроллер:

```
public function export2($id)
{
    $userid = Auth::id();

    $headers = array(
        "Content-Encoding: UTF-8",
        "Content-type" => "text/plain, charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=file.csv",
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires" => "0"
        // "charset" => "UTF-8"
    );
    $filename = "test2.csv";
    $reviews = DB::select("select * from profile_parameters_p where profile_id = " . $id);
    $columns = array('ReviewID', 'Provider', 'Title', 'Review', 'Location', 'Created', 'Anonymous', 'Escalate', 'Rating', 'Name');

    $callback = function() use ($reviews, $columns)
    {
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($file, $columns);

        foreach($reviews as $review) {
            fputcsv($file, array(iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251',$review->name)));
        }
        fclose($file);
    };
    return Response::download($filename, 'test.csv', $headers);
}
```

Comment: попробуйте в блокноте поменять кодировку на win-1251 или на utf-8

Comment: Насколько я знаю notepad не имеет такого функционала. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769311/how-windows-notepad-interpret-characters). Он читает и пробует интерпретировать содержимое как ANSI, либо UTF-8.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да все верно, блокнот не понимает utf8. Нужно было открыть в notepad++